# How do you filter for an EXACT word for RDD in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to Apache Spark and am running a Word Count example. After i got my list of words with their word counts i now want to filter for 4 specific words.

I have the below code written:

```
output_result = list_RDD.filter(lambda x: "can" in x[0])
```

when i run it i get all the words that contain "can" in it like "canada" , "candy" etc.. but i only want to return "can".

Is there also a way to get this to iterate over the list of words I'm looking for?

for example the words i want to search for are ['can', 'uni', 'over', 'day']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the solution using pyspark SQL functions.

If you want to filter lines based on whether they contain one of the words in words_list, you can use like:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
words_list = ['can', 'uni', 'over', 'day']
df.filter(func.col('col_with_text').rlike('(^|\s)(' + '|'.join(words_list) + ')(\s|$)'))
```

If you want to extract the strings matching the regular expression, you can use regexp_extract

```
df.withColumn('extracted_word', func.regexp_extract('col_with_text', '(?=^|\s)(' + '|'.join(words_list) + ')(?=\s|$)', 0))
```

Comment: I was using a RDD, do i have to use a dataframe if i want to do this? (sorry if thats a dumb question i am a beginner)

Comment: Yes. You would have to ise dataframes. That is also the preferred way instead of rdd.